# Zipping a file from memory in linux

Tags: c++, linux, zip

I'm working on application that must enrypt and zip files. So, I create some data in memory (text, binary or whatever), encrypt it and save to disk (file1 and file2). The I call e.g. "zip out.zip file1 file2 ".

I do not want to save this files to disk, but immediately create zip and pack these files from memory.

How should I do that?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could try to use the [zlib library](http://www.zlib.net/) to be able to create zip files from memory buffers.

The [boost:iostreams](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_46_1/libs/iostreams/doc/home.html) could also be a good solution.

Comment: Thanks, I've heard of zlib but I hoped I wouldn't use it :(

Comment: Thanks, I'm on the boost::iostreams reference now. I hope I will succeed.

Answer (score 1):

For [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) there is an extension for zip called minizip in the contribs. For minizip you can find code to work with in-memory buffers on the [authors page](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html):

> Justin Fletcher wrote a very simple implementation of a memory access method for the ioapi code ([ioapi_mem_c.zip](http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/ioapi_mem_c.zip)).

Answer (score 1):

Note that you must compress first and then encrypt. Encrypted data can't be compressed anymore.

Interestingly enough, I wasn't able to find a library to create ZIP files from C. [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) only allows to (de-)compress individual entries in a ZIP archive.

It comes with `contrib/minizip`; maybe that can get you started.

Comment: "must compress first then encrypt"... true if compression is required, but zip can also be used as a poor man's tar, for those Windowy types :-)